# How can I make sudo in 2 tabs ask for the password only once?

Tags: terminal, iterm, sudo

I have a script to automate starting a few servers on the terminal. These are server processes of the software I am developing. They can be recompiled and changed multiple times a day. The binaries can live in different places (working copies).

My script uses

```
 set sudo to do shell script "sudo -v "
```

to ask for the root password once, then creates a new iterm2 terminal window (and some tabs) and tries to start the servers with sudo:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
on run args
    set sudo to do shell script "sudo -v " -- to ask for password once only
    tell application "iTerm"
        create window with default profile
        tell current window
            tell current session
                write text "sudo /some/server"
            end tell
            -- more tabs and more sudos go here
        end tell
    end tell
end run
```

Everything worked fine on El Capitan, but not on High Sierra.

If the `sudo` password is not cached, the `sudo -v` asks for my password and then proceeds --- as expected. If I ran `sudo` before and the password is cached, the `sudo -v` does not ask for a password, again, as expected.
But in both cases each of the subsequent `sudo`s in the new window does ask for my password, making the whole thing inconvenient.

When I add `with administrator privileges` to the initial `sudo` it does ask for my password in a popup dialog but the following `sudo` calls with `write text` still ask for the password on the shell.
(I use `write text` and the terminal to keep an eye on these servers' outputs.)

I can run regular sudo commands just fine and it does cache the password.

How can I use `sudo` in Applescript in a new iTerm2 window and have it ask for the password only once?

**EDIT**: Looks like this is not related to Applescript but to iterm and High Sierra. When I open a terminal window with 2 tabs, I need to enter my password in both when I run e.g., `sudo ls`. After that both tabs have the sudo password cached, but running sudo in one tab does not make the other tab use the cached sudo password.

So the real question is probably: how do I get iTerm2 to cache the sudo password and share that between tabs and windows?

Comment: Have you considered setting these executables to run as root without a password, in the `sudoers` file? Have a look at the manual page for `sudoers`.

Comment: set thePassword to "Password" as string
    do shell script <<YourCommand>> ¬
        password thePassword with administrator privileges

Comment: @Gio Valerio, Personally I'd set the executables to run as root without a password, in the `sudoers` file before using `password` with `administrator privileges` as the _password_ is saved in plain text within the AppleScript file.

Comment: Your terminology here is problematic.  `sudo` isn't  launched *in* AppleScript.  `sudo` is called from a non-interactive, non-login shell called by AppleScript.  When you say "starting some servers" can you expand on what you mean?  Are you starting a service (like Apache) or are you starting a VM (like VirtualBox).  Also, is this something that you want to happen when the machine starts automatically, or only when you manually call the script?

Comment: not sure what happens to text in the applescript when you make an app out of them, however the idea was to test that it worked. Afterwards one can let the system (or the program) ask for the password

Comment: @Allan, I think while interesting, nonetheless the questions you've asked do not really address the issue, which is the OP has a script that works as intended and wanted in OS X 10.11 but not in macOS 10.13. Having run the script in each version of the OS, I see exactly what is being talked about. In OS X 10.11 if I run `sudo <script_name>, I'm prompted for my password and then the script runs all of the `write text "sudo /some/server"` commands without prompting again for a password. In macOS 10.13, all of the `write text "sudo /some/server"` commands wait for me to input the password again.

Comment: @Allan, So something has change to break what works in an earlier version of the OS.  BTW I really don't see anything wrong with the terminology used in the OP.

Comment: Robert, I can reproduce your issue but at the moment haven't investigated what's causing it. That's why I commented earlier, "Have you considered setting these executables to run as root without a password, in the `sudoers` file?"

Comment: @user3439894 - *If I ran `sudo` before and the password is cached, the `sudo -v` does not ask for a password, again, as expected.*  This is directly related to they type of shell he's in; `sudo` will not cache credentials in separate shells.

Comment: @Allan, You stated "`sudo` will not cache credentials in separate shells" and that is not totally true, case in point! I can reproduce the OP's issue! In OS X 10.8.6 and OS X 10.11.6 his script works as wanted and intended **however, is does not work in** macOS 10.13.1 as it did in OS X 10.8.6 and OS X 10.11.6. So, something changed between OS X 10.11.6 and macOS 10.13.1 that I tested under. So while  "`sudo` will not cache credentials in separate shells." is true in macOS 10.13.1 **it is not** true in OS X 10.8.6 and OS X 10.11.6 as tested. I'll admit I didn't think it would work but it did!

Comment: @user3439894 sudoers works nicely, I'm happy to accept that if you want to post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
Defaults !tty_tickets
```

to /etc/sudoers. Tested on 10.13.6 (High Sierra).

From the man page:

> If set, users must authenticate on a per-tty basis.  With this flag
>   enabled, sudo will use a separate record in the time stamp file for
>   each tty.  If disabled, a single record is used for all login
>   sessions.  This flag is on by default.